# Basic SQL Server Administration

Tags: sql-server

We just recently moved an internal database from access to SQL Server Express 2008.  Other then taking backups and applying patches are there basic administration tasks that I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Keep an eye on disk space.
2. Related - don't have your data and log files on the same partition as each other or the OS.
3. If you're running in Recovery Mode = Full, you also need to do transaction log backups.
4. There's a lot of performance analysis that you can do, if you need to. You might not need to.

Comment: Also I would suggest to limit memory usage dedicated for SQL Server as by default it is unlimited. So SQL Server can take much more memory that the amout it really needs for your database.

Comment: SQL Server Express is limited to using 1GB of memory, so nothing to worry about there.

Comment: This is incorrect for Express, it's limited to 1 GB. However, if you were running SQL Server non-Express on a machine that was also doing non_SQL things, you would want to limit the SQL memory. That's generally why you want SQL on a dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

google "sql server administration for beginners"

also, have a look here for books to read [BrentO](http://www.brentozar.com/best-sql-server-dba-books/books-for-sql-server-dbas/)

Answer (score 0):

The [pdfs](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_backup/offers/brad_exceptional_dba_ebook.htm) from redgate are pretty good - lots of things you can look at.

Your three main things to look after are...

1.Backups

2.Recovery

3.Security

Test a backup to another database name and make sure it works for you.  Make sure you are notified when the backups fail.

You'll want to do periodic maintenance on the indexes too.  I prefer this script -  http://ola.hallengren.com/

This type of stuff is a bit of a pain in sql express since there is no agent to run jobs.  You'll need to use the windows task scheduler or another tool to schedule .bat's to run.